Meaning of Second line of Shakespeare's Sonnet 66
I recently read Shakespeare's Sonnet 66 and I am quite confused as to what

As, to behold desert a beggar born

means. Sonnet 66 further goes on to talk about a list of things (supposedly) Shakespeare is tired of. Does it mean he is tired of beholding a desert while being born a beggar, where desert means a whole lot of barren belongings while deserving none?

"Desert" here is the concept of deserving, personified. Generally, desert can have a positive or negative sense, since people might deserve good or bad things. Here it is positive, as Shakespeare imagines [the idea of being worthy of reward] in the form of a beggar. Later in the sonnet he similarly imagines faith being abandoned ("forsworn"), foolishness having mastery over skill, etc. Each phrase has some sort of virtue or good quality being defeated by its opposite.
The Oxford English Dictionary uses this very line as an example of the noun desert, sense 1c, where the meanings are given as:

1 a. Deserving; the becoming worthy of recompense, i.e. of reward or punishment, according to the good or ill of character or conduct; worthiness of recompense, merit or demerit.
b. In a good sense: Meritoriousness, excellence, worth.
c. Personified.

Shakespeare uses the word in a similar way in The Two Gentlemen of Verona Act 2 Scene 4,

I know the gentleman
To be of worth and worthy estimation
And not without desert so well reputed.

The last line is saying that Antonio (the gentleman) deserves his high reputation.
Another OED quotation (for 1a) is from Caxton's translation of The Book of the Knight of the Tower (1483):

God rewarded eche of them after their deserte and meryte.

That is, God gave each of them what they deserved and merited.

Might be worth mentioning that while this noun is mostly archaic, it still survives in the expression "just deserts" (which is often misspelled as "just desserts" because of how it is pronounced).

The previous answers by Tsundoku and AlexG accurately explain the meaning of desert: in this context, it means "that which is deserving." The meaning becomes clearer when seen within the sonnet as a whole. The poem sets up the contrast between virtue and its reception in the world. For example, strength, instead of being able to flourish, is disabled by people who are morally weaker (limping)but have more influence (sway). Or simple truth is not valued for honesty, but treated as simplicity, i.e., stupidity. Similarly, desert is a beggar: merit is not rewarded, but struggles to survive. Seeing this disconnect between goodness and its fate, the speaker is disenchanted with life and calls out for restful death.

The editions I own all use the following text, i.e. without a comma:

As to  behold desert a beggar borne,

(Many editions modernise "borne" to "born", but not have a comma after "As".)
"As" means "for instance".
"Desert" is either merit personified or a person (or persons) deserving reward.
Based on this, the line can be paraphrased as follows:

For instance, to behold merit / those deserving reward being born into beggary.


Works consulted

Shakespeare: The Complete Sonnets and Poems. Edited by Colin Burrow. The Oxford Shakespeare. Oxford University Press, 2002.
Shakespeare: The Sonnets and A Lover's Complaint. Edited by John Kerrigan. The New Penguin Shakespeare. Penguin, 1986.
Willen, Gerard; Reed, Victor B. (editors): A Casebook on Shakespeare's Sonnets. New York: Thomas Y. Crowell, 1964.


"As," indicates that he's making a comparison to something in the context of the line prior to that. But the line is expressing the similarity of quality one would take on if they were to be born with nothing, only to realize that the place in which they find themselves is essentially comprised of nothing. Having nothing while having nothing around you is a literary manner of provoking mental imagery that encapsulates hopelessness. Rather vividly, in my opinion...
